# CRM 2013 to update statecode of Incident Resolution Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am quite new to this part of CRM. I want to set the StateCode field of Incident Resolution Entity.

I am trying the following way -

```
IncidentResolution res = new IncidentResolution();
res.IncidentId = new EntityReference();
res.IncidentId.LogicalName =Incident.EntityLogicalName;
res.IncidentId.Id = new Guid(row["id"].ToString());
res.StateCode = new OptionSetValue((int)IncidentResolutionState.Completed)); //This Following gives the error as System.Nullable<IncidentResolution.StateCode> cannot be assigned to--It is readonly.
CloseIncidentRequest req = new CloseIncidentRequest();
req.IncidentResolution = res;
req.Status = new OptionSetValue();
req.Status.Value = 5; // Problem Solved
service.execute(req);
```

The problem i am facing is to set the StateCode property for Incident Resolution Entity.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to set the StateCode of the IncidentResolution, only the Status of CloseIncidentRequest:

```
IncidentResolution res = new IncidentResolution
{
    Subject = "Resolved Sample Incident",
    IncidentId = new EntityReference(Incident.EntityLogicalName, new Guid(row["id"].ToString()))
};

// Close the incident with the resolution.
CloseIncidentRequest req = new CloseIncidentRequest
{
    IncidentResolution = res,
    Status = new OptionSetValue(5)
};
service.execute(req);
```